# How does an IDS system use PCAP to process malicious signatures?

Tags: ids

I have been wondering exactly how does an IDS system use packet captures (PCAP) to process and alert of malicious signatures?

Comment: What do you mean? That's a bit of a technical question, not even all IDS will do it based on pcaps, it can also be on generated logs.

Comment: I was hoping for like an analogy or explanation of how a Network-based IDS would use packet captures (PCAP) to process and alert of malicious signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: The IDS knows different protocols so it can see what runs over them. It can also interpret pcaps. A pcap is just a fileformat. The IDS understands this fileformat and can see all these different protocols. From here it just starts reading them. If it sees a protocol it understands, it will analyse it.

It's no different in concept than with logs, just different type of fileformat.